# Control regex empty matches

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to pull matches out of a fairly simple string. In my input string, the general pattern goes: `s(definitely a number)e(maybe some characters)s...`

Example Input: `s1e1s2e2s3es4e4`

Expected Matches Array: `[{1,1},{2,2},{3,''},{4,4}]`

I have tried:

`/s(\d)e([\d\:]+)?/g` and get `[{1,1},{2,2},{3},{4,4}]` which is really close, but I need the empty string in the third group.

and I naively try

`/s(\d)e(.*?)?/g` which gives me `[{1,''},{2,''},{3,''},{4,''}]`

I'd rather tell the regex to match any character instead of using the character class in the first example.

Aside from a simple working solution, an explanation of my misunderstanding would be great as well.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Doing this in PHP with preg_match_all(), but I'm testing the regex at regex101.com

Comment: It works as expected for me with `preg_match_all`, had to remove the `g` modifier.

Comment: The key was to use * instead of + to match an empty string

Comment: I tried your original version with `+` and it worked. However, it only works with `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER`, `PREG_SET_ORDER` leaves out `$match[2][2]`.

Comment: @barmar ah yes, I was using PREG_SET_ORDER and I didn't think that was the issue. Thanks for pointing that out as well.

Comment: To clarify my prior comment for the record, I can still use PREG_SET_ORDER and use * instead of + in my 'e' group, *or* I can use @Barmar's suggestion of using PREG_PATTERN_ORDER and leave the regex how it is.

Comment: Why waste your time with quantifiers. It either matches a digit or it doesn't. `s(\d)e(\d|)`. If it doesn't, the the lack of digit after 'e' simply sets capture group 2 to defined but empty. The match procedes to the next s(\d) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$pattern = '~s(\d)e([\d\:]*?(?=s\d|:|$))~';
```

Now your capturing group can match an empty string and is no more optional.

I have added a lookahead to check that there is an another "s\d" after or a `:` or the end of the string.

EDIT: Since the "s" is not allowed in the second capturing group, you can simply write:

```
$pattern = '~s(\d)e([^s]*)~';
```

Comment: ah, so simple. How could I do the same thing but without the character class after the 'e', so that it matches anything or an empty string until it hits the next 's'?

Comment: Use a character class that matches anything except `s`: `[^s]*`

Comment: @parker.sikand: Barmar has the answer, I will add an edit to my post.

Comment: @casimir but with the lookahead, then perhaps my input could be like `s1efasts2e2` and I would get `[{1,'fast'},{2,2}]` right? I don't actually need this for what I'm doing now but it's good for me to learn because I've never really understood the concept of lookaheads until I saw your answer.

Comment: @parker.sikand: indeed, the lookahead version allow you to match this.

Answer (score 2):

Use `preg_match_all` with the `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` option (the default). Then it won't leave out optional groups that don't match anything in the result.

Comment: Marking the other answer as correct only because it solved the problem on a general regex level, which is how I posed the question. However, this PHP specific info is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think this `s(\d)e(\d|)` should work on your examples. I don't know what the colon was for.